# Smart Device development for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, smart-device

I am currently assigned to migrate an existing Smart Device application built using visual studio 2005. I tried to migrate the application to Visual Studio 2017 without changing the framework and settings. I have already spent some time doing some research but no luck so far.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaO3N.png) is the error I'm encountering:

[image]

Any leads or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Please upvote-accept if the answer was helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking Windows Mobile 6.x projects. Unfortunately,

> support for mobile application development for versions of Windows Phone prior to Windows Phone 7.0

has been dropped with [Visual Studio 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sa69he4t(v=vs.100).aspx).

The last version that supported this application type is [Visual Studio 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sa69he4t(v=vs.90).aspx). Usually, you can install different versions of Visual Studio without problems. Nonetheless, this is a very old version and it might be worth to keep it on a separate machine.

You are stuck with Visual Studio 2005 or use VS2008. That's it.

Comment: Thanks. As work around I install VS2008 the latest VS version support Smart Device apps and compile the solution that is using Smart device and generates a class library for that and add it as reference. I am still waiting for the actual device to use for testing. Hopefully it will work.